# Why Firebase hosting slow to load static file?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, pingdom

I'm using Firebase hosting to store static files. I made a test on pingdom and the files are slow to load compare to others :

[image]

They say on Firebase that they are one of the fastest CDNs available. Why I can't get good performance?

Comment: Does this happen only once? Or also on subsequent loads?

Comment: I try multiple time and everytime its same

Comment: 85% of that is connecting and SSL handshake. The file was retrieved and delivered in 228ms. This isn't the CDN as far as I can tell.

Comment: You also don't have any useful information here. What is the source location of the request? Which CDN is being utilized? Is it in your region or a different region? How about the same info for your control group (i.e. the basis of your comparison for declaring this slow). Without that data, this is just opinion and troll bait.